# Java11/JavaFX11/Module Deployment Mess (Runnable Jar that works if clicked, but doesn't if ran from command line)

Tags: java, javafx

I'm new to Java11/all the overcomplicated module stuff.

**The Problem**

So I exported my Java11/JavaFX11 program from Eclipse as a Runnable JAR. If I click the JAR, it runs perfectly fine (Eclipse includes all of the module settings and JavaFX itself automatically in the runnable JAR). However, if I try to bundle the JAR with a JRE and run it via the command line with the following BAT file:

`@ECHO OFF
%~dp0\jre\bin\java -jar javaprogram.jar
pause`

I get:

`Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
Press any key to continue . . .`

How can I get it to just run the JAR file like it does when I click it?

**Ways I've tried to fix it**

The weirdest part is, if I just use:

`java -jar javaprogram.jar`

Which just accesses the *installed* JRE, it works again. It's only when I'm directly pointing it to a JRE at a specific path that it appears to break.

Alternatively, I'd just bundle JavaFX beside the JRE, but there doesn't seem to be a way to call `--module-path` with a relative path (googling this nets me a bunch of entirely unrelated stuff). It seems to demand an exact path, which isn't going to work if people are downloading a zip archive and extracting it. This would be redundant though because Eclipse is already packaging JavaFX with the JAR. I don't know why it's getting confused just because I'm calling it from the command line.

**The project's code**

The project I'm trying to get this to work with happens to be open source, so you can check out the code for it here:

https://github.com/SkyAphid/JDialogue

The main class is JDialogueCore.

**Closing**

I don't want to use installers since I think that's too bloaty. I'd like to be able to deploy my software like I always have by just putting them in an archive you can extract and run.

It's difficult to simply Google the problems as well since I keep getting completely unrelated results due to the broadness of the topic. Any direction/documentation relating to this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: How are you bundling the JRE? Using `jlink`? Please show the commands you're using.

Comment: FYI, the [new home for JavaFX](https://openjfx.io/) offers [HelloWorld tutorials](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) for both modular and non-modular apps.

Comment: Hey guys. I tweaked it a bit to remove any rudeness from it (I was really toasty when I wrote this). So firstly I apologize for that. Anyway, the JRE is included in its entirety in a folder beside the jar. I don't use any commands, I simply right click the project in Eclipse and export it as a runnable jar. As I mentioned in the post, the JAR actually works perfectly if I click it or run it from the windows command line normally. It's only when I try to use the included JRE that problems arise.

Comment: @BasilBourque I've read that, but it appears that it's requesting an absolute path for the JavaFX directory (I've tried some of those commands with no luck, it just gives the same error). If I'm going to go the route of just including it externally, I'd need to be able to reference it from the relative root path of the JAR. Do you know how I could do that?

Comment: Do you have an explicit `static void main` method?  Is it declared in the class which extends javafx.application.Application?

Comment: @VGR Yes, everything is built the way a standard application should be. It has a main() function, all of the APIs are packaged, the manifest is generated, and I even see a modules class in the JAR. It appears that the issue may be in my commands somehow since Java isn't registering any of that.

Comment: Is your `main` method declared in a class which extends javafx.application.Application?

Comment: @VGR Yes! Actually, let me just add the project to the main post since it's open source anyway. The main class is JDialogueCore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Java 8, 9, and 10 allowed a JavaFX [Application](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html) subclass to act as a main class for program startup, that is no longer the case as of Java 11.  Placing your `public static void main` method in a different class and making that class the main class solves the problem.  (Source: https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/issues/236)

Your command line invocation needs to specify both the location of the JavaFX jar files, and the location of JavaFX native libraries.  Normally these are the same location in the JavaFX SDK, but they must be specified in different ways:  the jar files go in the classpath or module path, while the native libraries’ location must be specified in a system property:

```
cd /d %~dp0
jre\bin\java -cp javaprogram.jar;javafx-sdk-11\lib -Djava.library.path=javafx-sdk-11\lib com.example.MyNonApplicationClass
```

If you define a `module-info.java` in your program, your .jar is a modular .jar, and you can benefit from the additional security of modules:

```
cd /d %~dp0
jre\bin\java --module-path javaprogram.jar;javafx-sdk-11\lib -Djava.library.path=javafx-sdk-11\lib -m com.example.myapp/com.example.MyNonApplicationClass
```

If your modular .jar file has a main class defined, you can omit the class name:

```
cd /d %~dp0
jre\bin\java --module-path javaprogram.jar;javafx-sdk-11\lib -Djava.library.path=javafx-sdk-11\lib -m com.example.myapp
```

Notice that relative paths work just fine with `--module-path`.  Relative paths use the current directory as a base.  The current directory is not changed merely by putting `%~dp0` in front of the invocation of Java.  The current directory is a property of the command line or script actively running, and can only be changed with commands like `cd` or `pushd`.